# Need help parsing file/writing script

Tags: parsing, text, scripting

Hey all, I have been doing nothing but web development over the last few years and haven't written any Java or C++ in what feels like forever.  I don't necessarily need to use these languages, so I'm entirely open to suggestion.  I was given an email list by a client to import into their mailchimp account yesterday and unfortunately, Mailchimp couldn't read the file.  It's a text file, but I don't believe it's tab delimited (which would make this much, much easier for me).

A small portion of the file (I've changed last names and email addresses) can be viewed here: http://sparktoignite.com/patients.txt

If anyone has suggestions on how I can get this into a Mailchimp readable format (csv, tab delimited txt, excel) please let me know.  I feel like 3 years ago I would've been able to do this in a matter of minutes, but given that I haven't touched anything other than RoR, PHP, and jQuery for the last few years, I don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, outputs TAB delimited file:

```
cat patients.txt | tr -d [[:blank:]] | tr "|" "\t" > output.txt
```

If you prefer csv, just change the last `"\t"` to `","`:

```
cat patients.txt | tr -d [[:blank:]] | tr "|" "\t" > output.txt
```

It messes up the header though. If you need to preserve header,  first couple of lines need to be skipped:

```
head -n2 > output.txt
tail -n+3 | tr -d [[:blank:]] | tr "|" "\t" >> output.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly!  I need to start learning bash tools.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, if any valid field value can contain whitespaces, this would get little more complicated than that.

Comment: @bradley Cool, glad it helped! Please see my note about whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on *nix, you can use tools like `awk`

```
awk -F"|"  'NR>2{$1=$1}1' OFS=","  file > newfile.xls
```

however, you stated that you know PHP, so why not stick to something you know. you can use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)/[fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

```
$output=fopen("out.csv","w");
$handle = fopen("file", "r");
if ($handle ) {
    $line=fgetcsv($handle, 2048, "|");
    $line=fgetcsv($handle, 2048, "|");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2048, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        fputcsv($output,$data,',');
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($output);
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I need to learn more about nix command line tools... I've only been on a Mac for a few months and haven't gotten into learning all the tricks.